# Any high quality Barcode scanning component available for windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, barcode, scanning

As the title. I am currently use ZXing to scan barcodes, but it can't recoginze some (about 25%) of the barcodes, anyone know a good quality component?

Comment: ZXing is good enough. Recognition rate depends on your barcode quality. What's the standards of your barcode, and how large is your barcode ?

Comment: Well, I tested on my book collection, they have different sorts size(standards) of barcodes, my observation is it is different for every scan even for same barcode, sometimes a barcode can be recognized with in a few seconds, but second scan will take half a mins.

Comment: recognition speed depends on light source & camera resolution & focus ability. ensure you have adequate distance between camera and barcode, such that the camera can focus properly.

Comment: I would really like to PAY for a good component.  ZXing does not provide an interface on WP8 like it does on Android. It expects an image to be passed to it. The capture of a frame of video is too small resolution to do this, and you lose autofocus when using the built in device. If you use a camera preview window, you get a max resolution stream to use which is unbearably slow. Seems there's no good answer here.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a library build using ZXing + Nokia Imaging SDK: http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Optical_Reader_Library_for_Windows_Phone_8